# permission error:- dynamic user:predicate modifying static procedure predicates/2

Tags: prolog, logic

I have some codes in Prolog, and when compiling I have some errors as the following:

```
 PERMISSION ERROR- dynamic user:examples/2: modifying static procedure examples/2
```

This is my partial code(that's for testing):

```
/* This part is for creating a cache and storing solutions, I got it from false */

:- dynamic(examples/2).

reset :- 
  retractall(examples(_, _)). 

eq(A, B) :-
  subsumes_term(A, B),
  subsumes_term(B, A).

cached_call(Goal) :-
  \+ (examples(First,_), eq(First, Goal)),
  copy_term(Goal, First),
  catch(
    ( Goal, 
      assertz(examples(First, Goal)),
      fail  
    ),    
  Pat,  
  (reset, throw(Pat))).

  cached_call(Goal) :-
    examples(First, Results),
  eq(First, Goal),
  Results = Goal. 

 /* my function, just for testing the cached technology */
  myFunction(V1, V2, Result) :-
  cached_call(keepValue(V1, V2, V1cover, V2cover)),
  Result is V1/V1cover + V2/V2cover.  /* V1cover, V2cover are the value of the first called time of myFunction, they become constants for next called times of myFunction */ 

  myFunction(0,0,0).   

  keepValue(V1, V2, V1cover, V2cover) :-
    V1cover is V1, 
    V2cover is V2.
```

When I compile this code, I got the error. Please tell me why? Thanks very much.

Comment: It should run correctly, the problem is not with your code. Maybe there is some problem with your swi installation.

Comment: You do not exploit caching: Everytime, you `reset`, before you call cached_call/1 Also, your renamings to `example/2` are not very helpful (to you).

Comment: Everytime I call reset in myFunction, it will reset the cache. So it will not store the result anymore. I also delete reset in myFunction but it doesn't work, and try to call reset before calling myFunction. The value of V1cover and V2cover are still not restored. I still get the same values of Result after calling myFunction many times.

Comment: Hi false, can you please help me check it? The code doesn't work for me when it doesn't restore the first value of V1cover and V2cover for the first called time of myFunction. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Give first your program without the caching, then we'll add it. OK?

Comment: Hi False, I just test a simple program as the above question. In prolog console, I call let say, myFunction(4,4,A). But it just returns the same value of A, 2 in this case all the time. So can you please tell me what did I do wrong? Thanks very much for your help.